# AngularJS returns Object object

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

I have a backend REST service that returns an array. I am trying to display the value returned by this REST service in one of my `<select>` using `ng-options`. However I get `[object Object]` on the lists.

Backend Java Rest service

```
@Path("/positions")
public class PositionRestService {

    ManagerService managerService = new ManagerService();   

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<String> getVacantPositions(@HeaderParam("iv-user") String uid) throws Exception{  
        Manager manager = managerService.getManager(uid);
        LdapSearch ldapProfile = new LdapSearch();
        List<String> vacantPositions = new ArrayList<String>();
        vacantPositions = ldapProfile.getChildPositions(manager.getPositionID());
        return vacantPositions;
    }
}
```

AngularJS Code - Service.js

```
services.factory('PositionsFactory', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/userfeed/rest/positions', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
        })

});
```

AngularJS - Controller.js

```
 app.controller('PositionCtrl', ['$scope', 'PositionsFactory', function ($scope, PositionsFactory) {    
    //$scope.positions = PositionsFactory.query();
    PositionsFactory.query({}, function (positionsFactory) {
        $scope.positions = positionsFactory;        
    })
}]);
```

My HTML code that uses the controller

```
 <select ng-model="myPosition" ng-options="position as position for position in positions"> </select>
```

Result 
I seee the follwing options on my list of options.

```
[object Object]
```

When I access the REST Service using my browser, I get the following array result which is what I am expecting on my option box above.

```
["CU13-00-00-004-","CU13-00-00-005-","CU13-00-00-006-"]
```

How can I get the values `CU13-00-00-004-, CU13-00-00-005- and CU13-00-00-006-` on my options using `ng-options`.

On using

```
{{positions|json}}
```

, I get following outcome:

```
[
```

{
    "0": "C",
    "1": "U",
    "2": "1",
    "3": "3",
    "4": "-",
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "-",
    "8": "0",
    "9": "0",
    "10": "-",
    "11": "0",
    "12": "0",
    "13": "4",
    "14": "-"
  },
  {
    "0": "C",
    "1": "U",
    "2": "1",
    "3": "3",
    "4": "-",
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "-",
    "8": "0",
    "9": "0",
    "10": "-",
    "11": "0",
    "12": "0",
    "13": "5",
    "14": "-"
  },
  {
    "0": "C",
    "1": "U",
    "2": "1",
    "3": "3",
    "4": "-",
    "5": "0",
    "6": "0",
    "7": "-",
    "8": "0",
    "9": "0",
    "10": "-",
    "11": "0",
    "12": "0",
    "13": "6",
    "14": "-"
  }
]

Looks like it has converted the array into JSON object and created a place holder for earch character. The  with ng-options show them as [object Object].

Please help. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you debug `$scope.positions = positionsFactory;` line and see the what `$scope.positions ` is ?

Comment: in your controller, please post the output of: `<pre>{{positions|json}}</pre>`. It should show the real structure of `positions`

Comment: I don't think it's your issue, but if you're using the same value for the name and the value of the option, you don't need the `<var> as <var>`.  It could just be: `position for position in positions`.

Comment: Hi @MaximShoustin I have updated the post, and included the <pre> result. Looks like it has converted my arrave value to each character and assigned it to the placeholder. Please have a look at the result posted above. Any comments?