# $resource returns Object with numeric attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read the return value from a CouchDB _update, which returns a string. I'm calling it via an AngularJS $resource, like so:

```
var cb = function(rtn){console.log(rtn);};
var foo = $resource('/myDb/_design/myDesignDoc/_update/thingie/:arg', {}, { update: {method: 'PUT'}});
foo.update({arg: "blah"}, null, cb);
```

This prints the following to the console:

```
Object { 0: "4", 1: "d", 2: "a", 3: "7", 4: "3", 5: "1", 6: "1", 7: "4", 8: "-", 9: "8", 51 more… }
```

The attributes with the numeric indexes **are** my desired output, but how to convert them back into a string?

I've tried `rtn.join("")` but it complains about not finding `rtn.join`. I suspect this of being obvious, but I'm stuck for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391274/angularjs-returns-object-object) (unanswered) question appears to be very similar to mine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510415/angularjs-resource-response-being-returned-as-array-of-characters-from-expressj) one was self-answered, suggesting returning a dictionary rather than a string. Simply returning a dictionary didn't work for me, but returning a JSON string *containing* a dictionary **did**, like so:

```
JSON.stringify({rtn_value: "the actual return value"})
```

Grumble. This should really be added to the AngularJS docs... maybe I'll do it (or better, someone who reads this should do so!)